# Spring and Hibernate - Use without hardcoding password in hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have developed a simple spring jar using Hibernate based on the tutorials provided here [Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_configuration.htm)

It is working as expected without issues. But I see the password is hardcoded in the file which is unacceptable in Production. Is there a way to call a method in the below statement which is  kind of dynamically assign the value to the key. Can you please guide on how to achieve the production ready hibernate config file. Thanks !!!

```
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.password">
     root123
  </property>
```

is it possible to do something like this

```
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.password">
     com.cfc.test.DBClass.getPassword(userName);
  </property>
```

Answer (score 0):

The password is ultimately going to be stored somewhere in plaintext. This is proven because you're trying to find a way to pass some property  to this file from another file.

A solution would be to not commit this file to your version control. Instead have each developer, or machine, create the file itself. That way the private credentials are never shared. If you wanted, you could maintain a template that contains the entire XML file excluding the password and suggest to the user to update the file.

If you're really bent on storing the value in some other file and then update the XML file before creating a service registry then you can simply read the properties file, update the xml file, then build the registry.

Comment: Hi Jason,

I am not going to pass the property to this file from another file. 

What I am trying to acheive is , calling a java method on this password tag, the method will make an API call to secure Password vault and retrieve the password during runtime and apply it here. 

This way everything happens at runtime securely so that no one can get the password. This is what I am envisioning . Please let me know if this doable.

Comment: Also if I dont commit the file in version control, then the packaged jar file from the build process will not have this file because build is dependent on the files in version control. I will get a runtime or deploy time error saying that file is missing